# ¿Cual es el código para ver una imagen en Pyhton usando numpy en jpg?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

Intente hacerlo con este, pero ya no me deja cambiar por otra imagen, ¿Que puedo 
hacer?

```
import Image as im
import numpy as np

data=np.random.random((617,346))

rescaled=(255.0/data.max()*(data-data.min())).astype(np.uint8)

im=im.fromarray(rescaled)
im.save('medusa.jpg')
```

Comment: Numpy no contiene utilidades para visualizar imágenes. Podrías utilizar PIL como lo hacen en este ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659378/6302727

Answer (score 0):

Como bien apunta @crlsktr en su comentario, librerías como PIL están diseñadas para eso!

Código de Ejemplo!

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

w, h = 512, 512
data = np.zeros((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
data[0:256, 0:256] = [255, 0, 0] # Habrá rojo en la esquina superior izquierda
im = Image.fromarray(data, 'RGB')
im.save('ejemplo.jpg')
im.show() # Para que la muestre
```